# Seeking global roads information preferably with traffic volume?

Tags: data, road, global

Im looking for a high quality global roads database. The only constraints I have is that it should be completely open (even foe commercial use)
I have looked into some publicly available databases like [SEDAC](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/groads-codata-roads-catalog-v1) and [TIGER](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-geodatabases.html). But SEDAC cannot be used for commercial purposes and TIGER is limited to US only.

I would also like if the data has traffic volume inherently (annual average will also work, daily estimates not required) or another traffic volume database which can be linked to the aforementioned roads database

Comment: GRIP: Global Roads Inventory Project http://geoservice.pbl.nl/geonetwork/srv/nl/main.home?uuid=8f1a8f7b-1474-43e1-ac4a-3d913197381a

Comment: @Mapperz Thank you. But I cant find a download to the dataset

Comment: it is downloadable from here in vector shapefile format http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/roads/  v3.0.0

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap is a crowd-sourced spatial dataset. The free download server (http://download.geofabrik.de/) provides access to daily-updated information. Not sure about traffic volumes though.

Comment: How will I be able to get road information from the osm xml file. I havent used osm earlier so I'm unaware of the node structure.

Comment: There is also shp export.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to add this answer here for other people who might be looking for a same or similar thing. What I did was downloaded the Shapefile for all roads from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/roads/ as per Mapperz's suggestion above. I downloaded [QGis](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and imported the Shapefile in it. The i managed to export the Shapefile as a CSV that can be now imported into my database. I do not know if the dbf file contains all the information and could be possibly imported directly without the need of shx and shp files.

Regarding the Traffic information, I could not find a global dataset of traffic information. I was looking for AADT (Annual Average Daily traffic) for all roads in the world. Instead I could download AADT datasets for UK and US staewise and them merge these together to form the table that I wanted.